# ASP.net SMTP Mail though Proxy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, smtp

How to setup `SMTPClient` in ASP.net with C# to send  email with provided proxy address ? or sending by detecting the system default proxy

I used the the following code in `web.config` but didnt work

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true">
      <proxy bypassonlocal="False" proxyaddress="http://192.168.101.3:8080/" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Did you try to declare your [proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) in the `Web.config`?

Comment: yes didn't work checked the `Local bypass thing.. ` in Default proxy too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send SMTP email through an HTTP proxy server.

Speak to the person administering your Internet gateway/firewall to ask what host they want you to direct outbound email to.

Comment: finally i think this is the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [article](http://www.shabdar.org/asp-net/72-send-email-using-your-gmail-account-or-using-gmails-smtp-server-in-aspnet.html), you simply have to declare your proxy configuration into your `Web.config` and try to change the port:

> If you are still having problems them try changing port number to 587

Edited my answer after your edit.